# Capturing device logs between specific time

Tags: logs, synchronization

We run a test script from a cron regularly , before initiating any actions this test script clears the /var/log/messages and after performing the actions it analyzes the data in /var/log/messages . This is not desired behavior as clearing of device logs is involved at start of test.

How can I capture device logs only between when test runs. So that test can analyze only that data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there are less kludgy ways, but you could run

```
tail -0f /var/log/messages > captured_logs
```

while your test script runs; or use

```
logger -i "Test started"
# ...test script...
logger -i "Test stopped"
```

(see [`logger`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)) and `grep` for the section afterwards from the complete log.  Beware, I'm not sure what happens when the logs turn over, so a **more robust** solution might be to read from [`syslogd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd)s socket (`-p` option), e.g. with [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)

```
socat UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/log STDOUT
```

where something more sophisticated than STDOUT might suit your needs better. (You could even run your own `syslogd` instance for the specific time, configured (`-a` option) to capture the logs from this socket.)